# Remove rows of a csv file which are in another csv file

Tags: r, excel

I have two Excel files, I want to remove rows from the first file excel1 who are not in the second file excel2 with an R insctruction.

Here is my escounted result. What should I do ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get this code. Of course maybe there are better approaches, but this do the trick you'd like!

```
excel.1 <- data.frame(V1 = c(4,4,8,6,7), V2 = c(5,3,6,9,2))

excel.2 <- data.frame(V1 = c(7,8,4), V2 = c(2,6,3))


a <- expand.grid(1:nrow(excel.1), 1:nrow(excel.2))
a <- t(a)
log.vec <- matrix(nrow = ncol(a), ncol = ncol(excel.2))
for (comb in 1:ncol(a)){
    log.vec[comb, ] <- excel.1[a[1, comb], ] == excel.2[a[2, comb], ]
}

log.vec <- cbind(log.vec, rowSums(log.vec))

equal <- a[, log.vec[, 3] == 2]

new.matrix <- excel.1[-equal[1,], ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much
Correct Answer

Answer (score 0):

You can read the csv files first

```
 excel1<-read.csv("excel1.csv", header=T)
 excel2<-read.csv("excel2.csv", header=T)
 excel1.excel2<-setdiff(excel1, excel2)
```

You can also refer to this post to help you prepare reproducible examples: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: sorry Obtained answer with instruction is wrong

Comment: I got the answer. You mean you didn't get the answer or what?

Comment: Obtain result by instructions above  is same rows in excel1 for me. 
But obtain result according example is:
Row1:(6,9)
Row2:(4,5)